# How to get the HTTP method in AWS Lambda in java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In an AWS Lambda java code, how can I get the HTTP method (e.g. GET, POST...) of an HTTP request coming from the AWS Gateway API?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your request mapping, that you set within the api-gateway.

If you stick with the default mapping, the following site has a section on how the event structure is formulated:
[Set up API Gateway Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html)

see section "Input Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration".

so in short.

```
event.httpMethod
```